# Supabase Edge Functions not recognizing import map passed in `npx supabase functions serve`

Tags: javascript, typescript, supabase, deno

I have two edge functions namely `create-payment-link` and `retrieve-payment-link` but the import map they're using is `/home/deno/flag_import_map.json`, and not the `import_map.json` file in the `functions` folder. Thus they're having a `x was not mapped in import map.` where x is a particular package they're using.

Both functions have these imports:

```
import { serve } from "server"
import * as cryptojs from "crypto-js";

import { config } from "dotenv";
```

And the contents of `import_map.json` is:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "server": "https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts",
    "crypto-js": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/crypto-js",
    "dotenv": "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts"
  }
}
```

This happens when trying to serve them both locally with: `npx supabase functions serve --debug --env-file ./supabase/.env --import-map ./supabase/functions/import_map.json`

Serving them one at a time with `npx supabase functions serve function-name --debug --env-file ./supabase/.env`  works though

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but why not move the import map to the functions folder?

Comment: It's already in the `functions` folder

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem. Seems like my VSCode Deno Language Server settings differ somehow from those read by Deno running on local-development container. But I didn't spot why, yet.

Answer (score 1):

The setting is taken in account at:

https://github.com/supabase/cli/blob/55192fe878c77fa347bb00ba102eadc88d738a3b/internal/functions/serve/serve.go#L27-L28
The code shows that `flag_import_map.json` is the one passed via `--import-map` flag.

I don't understand why they copy it in `/home/deno/` rather than  `/home/deno/functions/`. If one uses *relative* paths into the import-map, then those dependencies would get broken.
For what I understand the logic used by Supabase would work correctly **only** for remote Deno dependencies.

I suggest to keep your `import_map.json` where it is and let Deno resolve it, without trying to help it with the Supabase `config-map` flag.